# How to View HTTPRequest information

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I'm designing a web interface that is responsible for communicating with a piece of hardware. The hardware contacts the web page and sends an HTTP Request using POST that contains specific data in the body of http package using a "key=value" format.

Server-side I have code that does the following:

```
public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext curContext)
    {
        if (curContext != null)
        {
            HttpResponse response = curContext.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            response.BufferOutput = true;
            response.StatusCode = 200; // HttpStatusCode.OK;
            response.Write(response.StatusCode.ToString());
            response.End();
        }
    }
```

But what I really need is the necessary code to review the Body and retrieve the data (which is in text/plain format). I'm fairly new to this type of web programming so I don't know exactly what code to write to look in the curContext to get this information, or if I even have my override method correct.

I was expecting to have something available like curContext.Request.Body but this isn't the case. How can I see the raw POST data in body of the Request? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `curContext.Request.InputStream` or `curContext.Request.GetRequestStream()` to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`InputStream` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx) on the [`HttpRequest` instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) returned by the [`Request` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.request.aspx) exposed by the [`HttpContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) passed to your `ProcessRequest` method.

This will give you the contents of the `POST` request (which you can verify with a call to the [`HttpMethod` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.httpmethod.aspx) on the same `HttpRequest`).

Note that you'll have to use a [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) in order to convert the byte stream into strings which you'd then decode (since those key/value pairs should be url-encoded).

Fortunately, this is already done for you.  On the `HttpRequest` instance, you can use the [`NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) returned by the [`Form` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) to check for the values passed as part of a `POST` request with url-encoded key/value pairs like so:

```
public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext curContext)
{
    if (curContext != null) return;

    string value = curContext.Form["key"];

    // Do other processing.
    ...
```

Note that you can also use the [indexer on the `HttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx), but that combines *everything* exposed by the [`QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx), `Form`, [`Cookies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies.aspx) *and* [`ServerVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx) collections which I would say in this case is a bad idea, as you are *specifically* posting information and expecting that on the other side.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this! Got what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting the data in the body of the request in "key=value" format, it sounds like you are URL encoding form data (as long as you are delimiting the key/value pairs with an ampersand (&).

If that's the case, you should be able to use:

```
curContext.Request["key"]
```

And it will give you "value" in your example.